# json-server - empty database

Tags: javascript, json, json-server

I have simple `server.js` file:

```
var jsonServer = require('json-server');
var server = jsonServer.create();
var router = jsonServer.router('db.json');
var middlewares = jsonServer.defaults();


server.get('/date', function(req, res) {
    var db = router.db;
    var date = db.get('date');
    res.jsonp(date);
});

server.use(middlewares);
server.use(router);
server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('JSON Server is running');
});
```

In this same directory I have `db.json`:

```
{
    "date": "current"
}
```

But the `date` seems to be undefined.
When I console.log this variable inside `get` method call, I can see in console:

```
  __wrapped__: {},
  __actions__: [ { func: [Function: get], args: [Object], thisArg: [Function] } ],
  __chain__: true,
  __index__: 0,
  __values__: undefined
}
```

I run json-server through `node server.js`.

I will appreciate any help.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the package, but it looks wrong to access a data file with a `router` command.  Wouldn't you just `require` it?

Comment: https://github.com/typicode/json-server#add-custom-routes said that `const router = jsonServer.router('db.json')` should be used...

Comment: I was just reading that page, and it looks like it derives routes from the data, but your data doesn't match the form of the example data (and I can't see how a route would be made from your data).  Can you use the sample data they provide and see how it works then?

Comment: Okay, I will try than

Comment: No, I don't know what exacly you mean by "it derives routes from the data" and what is my data in the above example...

Comment: In db.json, place data of the form shown on readme page `{ "posts": [ { "id": 1, ....`

Comment: Still nothing. `db.get('posts')` returns same result as pointed in the question's description.

Comment: Okay, the problem is caused because `json-servers` looks for `db.json` from where `node server.js` is called and this is not the place where my `db.json` lives.
Great thanks for your efforts and good will @danh :)

Comment: glad you figured it out.  maybe post your solution to help others?

Answer (score 0):

Okey, it is always good to read the documentation carefully.
https://github.com/typicode/json-server#add-custom-routes

**The path you provide to the jsonServer.router function is relative to the directory from where you launch your node process.**

So, at the top of the `server.js` file it is good to add:

```
const router = jsonServer.router(path.join(__dirname, 'db.json'));
```